# Jquery slide up/down function -close/open all divs.. need only 1 div to open onclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I used below code to create toggle effect, as we are embedding html codes using javascript functions for CMS. Used Jquery mobile styles.

```
$('.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle').toggle(function(){
           $(".ui-collapsible-content").slideUp(
           function(){
               $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-shadow").addClass("ui-icon-plus");
               $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-shadow").removeClass("ui-icon-minus");
           }
           );
       },function(){ 
           $(".ui-collapsible-content").slideDown(
             function(){
               $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-shadow").addClass("ui-icon-minus");
               $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-shadow").removeClass("ui-icon-plus");
             }
           );
       });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role='collapsible' class='collapseRoomDetails secondLevel ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset' data-iconpos='right' data-collapsed='false'>
<h3 class='ui-collapsible-heading'>
    <a href='#' class='ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-btn-up-a' data-corners='false' data-shadow='false' data-iconshadow='true' data-wrapperels='span' data-icon='plus' data-iconpos='right' data-theme='a' data-mini='false'><span class='ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom'><span class='ui-btn-text'>Advance <span class='ui-collapsible-heading-status'> click to collapse contents</span></span><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-minus'>&nbsp;</span></span></a>
</h3>
<div class='ui-collapsible-content' aria-hidden='false'>
    <div class='displayContent'>
        <div class='displayContentLeft'></div>
        <div class='displayContentRight'><p>Bay of Islands Hotel offers are even better value when you book ahead.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div data-role='collapsible' class='collapseRoomDetails secondLevel ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset' data-iconpos='right' data-collapsed='false'>
<h3 class='ui-collapsible-heading'>
    <a href='#' class='ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-btn-up-a' data-corners='false' data-shadow='false' data-iconshadow='true' data-wrapperels='span' data-icon='plus' data-iconpos='right' data-theme='a' data-mini='false'><span class='ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom'><span class='ui-btn-text'>Purchase<span class='ui-collapsible-heading-status'> click to collapse contents</span></span><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-minus'>&nbsp;</span></span></a>
</h3>
<div class='ui-collapsible-content' aria-hidden='false'>
    <div class='displayContent'>
        <div class='displayContentLeft'></div>
        <div class='displayContentRight'><p>Bay of Islands Hotel offers are even better value when you book ahead.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not have good knowledge jquery function. Dont know how to make only clickable container to toggle and other to hide..

Comment: Wouldn't that be an accordion?

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/accordions/

Answer (score 1):

You are appending an *enhanced* HTML markup of a *collapsible* on `.ready()`. The latter function shouldn't be used in jQuery Mobile, use its' special events to have control over your elements.

Static collapsible's HTML markup is as follows. It get enhanced by jQuery Mobile once *page* is initialized. You don't have to *statically* add any *enhancement* classes to the below markup.

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>Contents</p>
</div>
```

If you wish to create collapsible *dynamically*, you need to *enhance* it manually by calling `.collapsible()` on the created element. In order to instruct jQM to add all necessary classes and bind events to it. Collapsibles in jQM have to special events, `collapse` and `expand` which you can listen to them and execute some function once they trigger.

I have made a short demo to show you how to create *collapsible* on the fly. I have used jQM page event `pageinit` to append the items as well as bind events. This event is equivalent to `.ready()` and it fires once per *page* div. Moreover, I have created *collapsibles* using `.collapsible()` enhancement function.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    var data = [{
        "name": "Name 1",
            "content": "contents here..."
    }, {
        "name": "Name 2",
            "content": "different contents here..."
    }];

    /* Read aray to create two collapsibles
       and append them to content div */

    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $("[data-role=content]").append($("<div/>", {
            "data-role": "collapsible"
        }).append($("<h3/>").text(value.name)).append($("<p/>").text(value.content)).collapsible({
            collapsedIcon: "plus", /* set collapsed icon */
            expandedIcon: "minus"  /* set expanded icon */
        }));
    });

    /* listen to clicks on heading button
       if current clicked collapsible is expanded 
       collapse it and expand the other
       in case you have more than two collapsibles 
       the below code should be amended */

    $(".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").on("click", function (e) {
        var current = $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible");
        if (current.hasClass("ui-collapsible-collapsed")) {
            $(".ui-collapsible-content", current).slideDown(function () {
                current.trigger("expand");
            });
            $(".ui-collapsible").not($(current)).find(".ui-collapsible-content").slideUp(function () {
                $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible").trigger("collapse");
            });
        } else {
            $(".ui-collapsible-content", current).slideUp(function () {
                current.trigger("collapse");
            });
            $(".ui-collapsible").not($(current)).find(".ui-collapsible-content").slideDown(function () {
                $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible").trigger("expand");
            });
        }
    });

    /* expand first collapsible */

    $(".ui-collapsible").first().find(".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").click();

});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/JnhwP/)**

Comment: Hi Omar, Thanks for your great help!! One last question.. Last time when we embed expand/collapse div container through javascript, its not loaded with default jquery mobile styles (Jquery mobile scripting not loading)..but JQM works in other pages & even in this page when we embed as HTML content. Only not loading when we embed through javascript.

Comment: @venkatesha dynamically added items should be enhanced manually, unlike static ones which get enhanced once page is created. I'm it worked for you. If you more question, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Hi Omar, sorry..i cant able to understand your reply. we are trying add "<div class="content">blah..blah</div> through javascript to append inside container. These part working now. only issue here is JQM JS file not loading and Styles are missed out. Not sure why JS script not loading only this part. JQM script already included in header

Comment: @venkatesha Please post another question with more details. Mentioned whether you're using _multi-page_ or _single page_ model. If this answers helps you, pls mark it as correct.

Comment: @venkatesha do you still need more clarification?